# Changing path for media upload folder in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, images, media

Does anyone know how to remove `/sites/#blog_id/` from Multisite media path? 
We have all images uploaded in main `/public_html/images/` and when it connected to the media library all images on sub-domains are broken because of WPMU ads `/sites/#blog_id/` individually for each sub-domain. That creates problem to use same stock images across different blogs. 
I'm looking for a solution to make all uploaded images stored in one place and being equally accessible from any sub-blog.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered [Hook filter to change wp_upload_dir() path in multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/261931/hook-filter-to-change-wp-upload-dir-path-in-multisite) , including code to hook into the `upload_dir` hook.

Note that there is a setting in wp-config.php for the 'base' upload folder

```
define(‘UPLOADS’, ‘wp-content/myimages’);
```

So with this code, the uploads folder is `wp-content/myimages`.

But, that changes the place WP looks for the media, so you will have to move existing media files to the new location, if you use that setting to change the 'base' upload folder.